# Getting native ringtones in ionic app?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing a ionic app which has functionality to set reminder in app. After one button click i want to open up list which contains native ringtones of msg for both android and ios. How can i get these sounds in a list and then play it in my local notification of reminder. Thanx in advance

Answer (score -1):

You can look into Cordova plugins that will provide you an interface to load up the system ringtones.

> A Cordova / Phonegap ringtone plugin for Android. Set an audio file as ringtone, notification tone or alarm tone.

This could be helpful : https://github.com/Hiraqui/cordova-plugin-ringtone

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, the OP asked to list the ringtones present in the device and play them, your answer specifies how to make an existing audio file as a ringtone.